# C Cursor Question

Tags: c, cursor, turbo-c

I'm a newbie in Turbo C... Just want to ask what is the first thing should I do to enable the use of cursor. I'd like to control the cursor and redefine keys on the keyboard as well. Please give me steps, thanks in advance!

Comment: I am just perplexed... What is ANSI.SYS and CONFIG.SYS?

Comment: Those are DOS era relics that you shouldn't have to know--or care--about.  (Much like Turbo C.)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI.SYS

Comment: @Hostile Fork: where I can find the CONFIG.SYS or CONFIG.NT file?

Comment: You probably can't (or shouldn't) be modifying those on your computer if it is running a modern version of Windows.  I question your motivation for wanting to do this, -but- if you really want to run old DOS software, use an emulator like DOSBox.  It should have a CONFIG.SYS and AUTOEXEC.BAT prominently in the "C:\" directory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSBox

Answer (score 4):

When dinosaurs ruled the Earth and some professional programmers actually used Turbo C, the cursor support was handled through routines in an include file called `conio.h`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

You won't find a lot of Internet-era writings about this.  But I managed to find a reference to someone using this in [an online document](http://www.scribd.com/doc/50033656/10/GRAPHICS-FEATURES-IN-C):

```
/* Program to display text using special functions*/
#include <conio.h>

main (){
    int n,m,;

    /* clears the screen */
    clrscr ( );

    /* sets the text mode to 80 columns color*/
    textmode (3);

    /* SETS THE TEXT COLOR*/
    textcolor (4);

    /* sets the text background color */
    textbackground (2);

    /* Positions to 5th row and 14th column*/
    gotoxy (5,15);
    printf ("Enter two numbers:");
    scanf ("%d %d", &n, &m);
    gotoxy (10,15);
    printf ("Entered numbers are %d and %d \n\n", n,m);
}
```

It's not clear if you mean you want to redefine keys such that while your program is running, when a certain key is pressed by the user, it produces a different character output.  If so you will probably want to use something like `bioskey()`...because `getch()` only reads characters and not things like function keys or modifiers:

http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Turbo_C/bioskey.html

Comment: @Hostile Fork: what if I'm going to move the cursor diagonally? I can't get it with this code- `printf("\x1B[B");` where `\x1B` is an escape character numerical value 1B hex(27 decimal); `[` is a bracket that always precedes specific code; and `B` specific action:cursor down

Comment: You're asking questions about ANSI Escape Codes of people who didn't suggest you use them.  Windows has embraced a console API and phased out ANSI support in the terminals by default, and it's of questionable value to enable it especially when no one else's machine has it on.  You won't find an easy way to call the console API from something as old as Turbo C: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Have you tried entering the program code that I gave as the answer to this question which uses conio.h?  That gives you the ability to position the cursor arbitrarily in an 80x25 screen.  Now admittedly it doesn't play very well with the modern resizable Windows console.  But you need to accept if you're using Turbo C that you'll be programming to the expectations of that era.  For instance, you won't be doing graphics in OpenGL or DirectX...you'll be using the Borland Graphics Interface ("BGI") and it's gonna be clunky but that's what goes with that compiler.

Comment: And yes, you probably can get ANSI.SYS installed by editing a hidden file in your Windows 7 filesystem, and reboot, and then your ANSI Escape Codes might start working.  But any computer you want to run your program on would then have to do this process.  If you used a more modern compiler with "curses" you'd be a lot better off: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)

Comment: @Hostile Fork: I am using WindowsXP(SP3) and I dont find that hidden file. I think, to enable the ANSI.SYS, there's something to modify in CONFIG.SYS file.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the gotoxy(int x, int y) function, which is not ANSI C, but a Borland extension in Turbo C. It places the cursor at the coordinate (x, y) in a text mode display.

As far as redefining keystrokes, are you looking at doing this within your program or within the ide? If within your program, you can use the scan code returned by getchar() and alter it before re-outputting it with putchar(char c). As far as defining key bindings for ide functions, I THINK (it's been a long time) the user interface allowed that within the menus.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: ahmm... how to install ANSI.SYS? and how can I find it?